ng build throws error @angular/core/core has no exported member 'eeFactoryDeclaration'
getting this error while upgrading existing angular project from angular 9 to angular 10
I have tried to upgrade the angular version using below command:
npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10

Looks like you have dependencies that don't support v10.
